# decltype of pointer to class accessing its () operator

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, decltype

I have following class

```
template<class T> class CT
{
  T& operator()(int i,int j) const noexcept
  { return indx[i*N+j]; }
  private:
  T  *indx;
  int N;

};
```

Now some where in my application I have something as the following

```
CT<double> arr, (...);
(...)
decltype(arr) *alias;
if(usearr)alias = &arr;
(...)


alias(0,0) = 3.0; // Compiler ERROR!
```

The compiler complains that the object type I am accessing through `decltype` is not a function or function pointer.

The problem can be solved if I remove the pointer in declaring `alias` and replaces the line to an assignment overload

```
decltype(arr) alias;
if(usearr)alias = arr;
```

What is wrong with the former approach ?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. It should be `operator()(<params>)`. There is no need to apply `const` if you are taking parameters by value. Lastly, show the complete code rather than keep everyone guessing what's in those `...`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but when `alias` is created it has an unspecified value. If the code doesn't assign a real address or a null pointer to it, just about anything that it does with `alias` introduces undefined behavior. A more appropriate initialization could be `decltype(arr) *alias = usearr ? &arr : nullptr;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype(arr)` yields the type of `arr`, i.e. `CT<double>`, then `decltype(arr) *` yields the type `CT<double> *`, which is a pointer to `CT<double>` and you can't call `operator()` on it directly.

You can dereference it then call `operator()` like `(*alias)(0,0)`.